# What is the source of the cartoon against the US war in Vietnam ending with "I just get killed"?

Tags: united-states, vietnam-war, vietnam

There was an antiwar cartoon that showed a sequence of persons from the United States, each with words suggesting they had little or no responsibility for the war, e.g. "I just do the administration", "I'm only a medic", "I just supply the army", or "I'm just a politician". Then at the end it had an image of a Vietnamese person wearing a conical Vietnamese hat, saying "I just get killed".

What was the source? Is there a webpage that has the actual image? What are the publication and author details?

It may possibly have been drawn by Ron Cobb.

I have searched at [CartoonStock](https://www.cartoonstock.com), [The Cartoon Bank](https://www.cartoonbank.com), and [Cartoon Collections](https://www.cartooncollections.com) without success.